# List rearrangement

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list:

```
lis = {{1,2,3},{"True",3,4,5},{6,5},{3},{6,4},{"True",2,1},{5},{5,6},{7,8,9}}
```

I want to make a new list consisting of elements of lis that begin with "True", and include the next two elements directly following, thus making triplets:

```
res = {({"True",3,4,5},{6,5},{3}},{{"True",2,1},{5},{5,6}}}
```

I can't see how to use Cases here.  Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`SequenceCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html):

```
SequenceCases[lis, {{"True", ___}, _, _}]
```

> ```
> {{{"True", 3, 4, 5}, {6, 5}, {3}}, {{"True", 2, 1}, {5}, {5, 6}}}
> ```

[`Split`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html) + [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html):

```
Cases[p : {{"True", ___}, ___} :> Take[p, UpTo[3]]] @ Split[lis, #2[[1]] != "True" &]
```

> ```
> {{{"True", 3, 4, 5}, {6, 5}, {3}}, {{"True", 2, 1}, {5}, {5, 6}}}
> ```

[`Position`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html) + [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html):

```
lis[[# ;; UpTo[# + 2]]] & /@ Flatten@Position[lis, {"True", ___}]
```

> ```
> {{{"True", 3, 4, 5}, {6, 5}, {3}}, {{"True", 2, 1}, {5}, {5, 6}}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Defining a utiilty function that appends subsequent positions to the list. This can be changed as required without affecting other parts of the solution.

```
lp2[k_List] := {First@k, First@k + 1, First@k + 2}
```

Test: `lp2[{2}]` (* {2,3,4} *)

```
sel = lp2 /@ Position[lis, {"True", ___}]

Part[lis, #] & /@ sel
```

> {{{"True", 3, 4, 5}, {6, 5}, {3}}, {{"True", 2, 1}, {5}, {5, 6}}}

Answer (score 4):

Selecting indices, and do something :

```
lis[[# ;; # + 2]] & /@ 
 Select[Range[Length[lis]], lis[[#, 1]] === "True" &]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
lis = {{1, 2, 3}, {"True", 3, 4, 5}, {6, 5}, {3},
      {6, 4}, {"True", 2, 1}, {5}, {5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

---

Using `SequenceSplit`:

```
patt = {{"True", ___}, _, _};

DeleteCases[SequenceSplit[lis, s : patt :> s], Except[patt]]

(*{{{"True", 3, 4, 5}, {6, 5}, {3}}, {{"True", 2, 1}, {5}, {5, 6}}}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[lis, {___, s : PatternSequence[Sequence @@ patt], ___} :> {s}]

(*{{{"True", 3, 4, 5}, {6, 5}, {3}}, {{"True", 2, 1}, {5}, {5, 6}}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = 
 {{1, 2, 3}, 
 {"True", 3, 4, 5}, {6, 5}, {3}, {6, 4}, 
 {"True", 2, 1}, {5}, {5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

Using `SequencePosition` and `Take`

```
p = SequencePosition[list, {{"True", ___}, _, _}]
```

{{2, 4}, {6, 8}}

```
Take[list, #] & /@ p
```

{{{"True", 3, 4, 5}, {6, 5}, {3}}, {{"True", 2, 1}, {5}, {5, 6}}}