# How to use wildcards in SequenceCases

Tags: list-manipulation

The final task is to revise the question I posed at [list rearrangement](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255975/list-rearrangement):

I now start with this list:

```
lis = {{1,2,3},{"True",3,4,5},{6,5},{3},{6,4},{"Truex",2,1},{5},{5,6},{7,8,9}}
```

I want to make a new list consisting of elements of lis that begin with "True" (*or "True" followed by any further string characters*), and include the next two elements directly following, thus making triplets:

```
res = {({"True",3,4,5},{6,5},{3}},{{"Truex",2,1},{5},{5,6}}}
```

Again the task seems to be to get SequenceCases to recognize the pattern that allows it to pick up elements with "True" as well as "True*"  Thanks again for ideas.

Comment: `SequenceCases[lis, {{_?(StringContainsQ[ToString@#, "True"] &), ___}, _, _}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SequenceCases[lis, {{_String?(StringMatchQ["True*"]), __}, _, _}]
```

> ```
> {{{"True", 3, 4, 5}, {6, 5}, {3}}, {{"Truex", 2, 1}, {5}, {5, 6}}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = 
 {{1, 2, 3}, 
 {"True", 3, 4, 5}, {6, 5}, {3}, {6, 4}, 
 {"Truex", 2, 1}, {5}, {5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
```

Using `SequencePosition` and `Take`

```
p = SequencePosition[list, {{x_String /; StringTake[x, 4] == "True", ___}, _, _}]
```

{{2, 4}, {6, 8}}

```
Take[list, #] & /@ p
```

{{{"True", 3, 4, 5}, {6, 5}, {3}}, {{"Truex", 2, 1}, {5}, {5, 6}}}